# Amazon EC2 で Ubuntu を作ると「su -」でパスワードを聞かれる

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

「AWSをはじめよう」という本でEC2サーバーの構築について勉強しています。
本ではCentOSベースのAmazon Linuxを使っていますが、ローカルのWSLでUbuntuを使い慣れているのでUbuntuを使いました。
規定のアカウント名ubuntuでSSH接続するところまで出来ています。

本では以下のコマンドでrootになってみましょうみたいなことを言われましたが、UbuntuのEC2でこれをやるとパスワードを聞かれました。

```
$ su -
```

`sudo` でroot権限のコマンド（`apt update` など）は（パスワードなしで）実行できますが、それだけで学習しつづけられるでしょうか。
Amazon Linux、Ubuntu、suのパスワード、sudoのパスワードについて特に知るべきことはあるでしょうか。

Comment: 重複候補: [sudoにはrootのパスワードが必要ないので意味がないのでは？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/49070)

Comment: ありがとうございます。suとsudoerの一般的な違いではなく、EC2におけるAmazon LinuxとUbuntuの既定値という個別性の問題かと思って質問しました。

Comment: WSL の Ubuntu で `su -` を実行した場合にはどうなるのでしょうか？

Comment: デフォルトでsudoresがどうなってるかだけの話では。。
必要に応じて編集すればいいだけかと。。sudores修正しくると二度とrootになれない哀しみ。visudoすればいいだけなんですが。プロビジョナで一度しくりました。

Comment: > WSL の Ubuntu で su - を実行した場合にはどうなるのでしょうか？
こちらもパスワードを求められ、設定したことがないのでログインできなくなりますね。なるほど

Answer (score 1, accepted):

参照している書籍ではどのような意図で「`su -` で root になってみよう」としているのか分かりませんが、root 権限 (=管理者権限) が必要なら通常は `sudo` での運用で十分です。

---

`su -` で root アカウントに切り替えようとした場合、「root アカウントのパスワードを知っている」「 **root アカウントにパスワードが設定されている** 」必要があります。

EC2 のインスタンスで作成したマシンには、root パスワードが設定されていないようなので、例えば以下のような手順で設定しておく必要があります。

**参考:**
[AWSの初期設定でrootパスワードを設定する](https://qiita.com/shanonim/items/5496e0c6f6bf09e76f7c)

- 一般ユーザーでログイン
- `sudo su -` で root 権限に昇格
- `passwd` コマンドで root アカウントにパスワードを設定

Answer (score 1):

> Amazon EC2 で Ubuntu を作ると「su -」でパスワードを聞かれる

手元の環境の Ubuntu 20.04/21.04 の場合、PAM(Pluggable Authenticaton Modules)によって設定を変更することが可能です。

##### `/etc/pam.d/su`

> # Uncomment this if you want wheel members to be able to
> # su without a password.
> #auth       sufficient pam_wheel.so trust

Ubuntu Linux の場合、デフォルトの設定では `wheel` グループが存在しません。`wheel` グループを作成しても良いかと思いますが、管理者グループということで既存の `adm` グループに設定してみます。

```
auth       sufficient pam_wheel.so trust group=adm
```

```c
$ lsb_release -ir
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Release:    20.04

$ id
uid=1000(nemo) gid=50(staff) groups=50(staff)
$ su -
Password: 

$ sudo usermod -a -G adm nemo

$ id
uid=1000(nemo) gid=50(staff) groups=50(staff),4(adm)
$ su -
root@host-0-0-0-0:~# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

> sudo でroot権限のコマンド（apt update など）は（パスワードなしで）実行できますが、

##### `sudo(1)`

> **-i, --login**
>
> Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry as a login shell. This means that login-specific resource files such as .profile, .bash_profile or .login will be read by the shell.

```c
$ sudo -i
root@host-0-0-0-0:~# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

> Amazon Linux、Ubuntu、suのパスワード、sudoのパスワードについて特に知るべきことはあるでしょうか。

PAM(Pluggable Authenticaton Modules) については知っておいても損はしないでしょう(得をするという保証はありませんけれども)。

```c
$ man -k pam
PAM (7)              - Pluggable Authentication Modules for Linux
capability.conf (5)  - configuration file for the pam_cap module
faillock.conf (5)    - pam_faillock configuration file
group.conf (5)       - configuration file for the pam_group module
limits.conf (5)      - configuration file for the pam_limits module
pam (5)              - portable arbitrary map file format
pam (7)              - Pluggable Authentication Modules for Linux
pam-auth-update (8)  - manage PAM configuration using packaged profiles
pam.conf (5)         - PAM configuration files
pam.d (5)            - PAM configuration files
pam_access (8)       - PAM module for logdaemon style login access control
                  :
```